# Extract Hidden Layer Vector from RNN Tensoflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm very unfamiliar with TensorFlow, but I'm trying to get a project working.

I've trained an LSTM using the following code: https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow

This is great, and using sample.py I get great output data. However, I'm not very interested in generating output data. What I want to do is extract the hidden layer vector from the last step of the LSTM.

Basically, I would like to return an array of the hidden values which would normally be passed to the next time step in the LSTM (128-dimensional vector for this particular model, which is specified in train.py) immediately after the following segment of model.py is run:

```
def sample(self, sess, chars, vocab, num=200, prime='The ', sampling_type=1):
        state = self.cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32).eval()
        for char in prime[:-1]:
            x = np.zeros((1, 1))
            x[0, 0] = vocab[char]
            feed = {self.input_data: x, self.initial_state:state}
            [state] = sess.run([self.final_state], feed)
```

I'm not sure how to do this in Tensorflow, any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you have not seen this, https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html

Comment: I read through the page, but I'm having trouble "restoring" the hidden state variable of the MultiCellRNN object because I don't really know what its name is. Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Since this isn't a model I created from scratch -- it's comprised of BasicLSTMCell -- I'm not sure how to access its variables